# Repo Sync : Fatal Error

Tags: android, git, ssl, repo

I keep geting this
after repo sync
**"fatal: remote error: SSL is required"**

```
[new tag] android-4.3_r0.9 -> android-4.3_r0.9
[new tag] android-4.3.1_r1 -> android-4.3.1_r1
[new tag] android-4.2_r1 -> android-4.2_r1
[new tag] android-4.2.2_r1.2 -> android-4.2.2_r1.2
[new tag] android-4.2.2_r1.1 -> android-4.2.2_r1.1
[new tag] android-4.2.2_r1 -> android-4.2.2_r1
[new tag] android-4.2.1_r1.2 -> android-4.2.1_r1.2
[new tag] android-4.2.1_r1.1 -> android-4.2.1_r1.1
[new tag] android-4.2.1_r1 -> android-4.2.1_r1
[new tag] android-2.3.7_r1 -> android-2.3.7_r1
[new tag] android-2.3.6_r1 -> android-2.3.6_r1
[new tag] android-2.3.6_r0.9 -> android-2.3.6_r0.9
[new tag] android-2.3.5_r1 -> android-2.3.5_r1
fatal: remote error: SSL is required
fatal: remote error: SSL is required
fatal: remote error: SSL is required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://osdir.com/ml/repo-discuss/2012-01/msg00338.html) mentions

`.repo/manifest.xml` should list the review URL.
The default from the AOSP servers says `https://`.
So I don't know why this is `http://` for you.

Check your `.repo/manifest.xml` content.

Answer (score 0):

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#using-authentication
To protect the servers against excessive usage,  force authenticated access by using the following manifest URI: https://android.googlesource.com/a/platform/manifest. 
so , use **https://**